# Autofill service enable via Activity Results API

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, autofill, registerforactivityresult

I'm try to register an `ActivityResultContract` for `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE` using kotlin and AndroidX:

```
class AutofillContract() : ActivityResultContract<Any?,ActivityResult>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Any?): Intent
        = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE)

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): ActivityResult
        = ActivityResult(resultCode, intent)
}

val afrl = registerForActivityResult(AutofillContract()) {
    if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) ...
    else ...
}
```

However, when I try to use it:

```
afrl.launch(AutofillContract().createIntent(this, null))
```

I get *IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode*, which I presume was triggered by an internal `startActivityForResult()` call.

I haven't used a custom `ActivityResultContract` before, and although it seems simple it also seems a bit sketchy to me -- I'm not sure if regarding the input as irrelevant (`Any?`) is the way to go, but it does seem irrelevant in this case (the first version used `Intent` as the input type but there doesn't seem to be a point, and the problem, *"Can only use lower 16 bits..."* was the same).

I'm using `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha08`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157227983), you get that error when you are using an older version of Fragments.

You must also upgrade your version of Fragments to `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha08`.

Comment: There's a Lint check for exactly this case as mentioned in the [Activity release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.0-alpha07)